# is there a way to get rid of the word "show all posh with "blablabla" label in blogger?

Tags: html, blogger

[screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDqqj.png)

as we know, on the blogger platform we do not include posts into sub of the page, finally I use label tricks embedded on the page so that when visitors click will be directed to all posts labeled in accordance with the page.
but I have trouble eliminating this text "show POST WITH "blablabla" LABELS."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for `<data:view.search.resultsMessageHtml/>` and remove the parent div of it.

It looks a bit like this:

```
<span class='query-info query-success'><data:view.search.resultsMessageHtml/></span><a class='show-more' expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl'><data:messages.showAll/></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can replace

```
<data:view.search.resultsMessageHtml/>
```

with

```
<data:view.search.label/>
```

it will remove the "show posts with" and the label name will remain, it's good for aesthetics to show the label as the title...